# Azure mulit-tenant application not getting tokens with newly defined scopes

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I am developing a Azure multi-tenant application that uses scopes from the Microsoft Graph API and the Windows Azure Active Directory resources. We are using the **v1 OpenID auth code flow.**

Recently we added a few more requested scopes to the Microsoft Graph API, we prompted users to reauth using `prompt=admin_consent` and `resource=https://graph.microsoft.com` on our `/common/oauth2/token` exchange.

When the user is prompted to accept scopes again you can see the newly requested scopes and the call seems to complete successfully, we receive a new `access_token`.

However the scopes that come back in the response AND the embedded JWT claim for scopes only lists a small subset of the requested scopes and they also only seem to be from one of the resources (Windows Azure Active Directory).

We are receiving 403s for the new scopes so I do not think it is a issue of not correctly populating those scope fields.

**Does anyone know why the auth flow would not return a token with the newly requested scopes?**

Here is a listed of my requested scopes:

Windows Azure Active Directory

- Read and write directory data (Application)
- Access the directory as the signed-in user (Delegated)
- Read and write directory data (Delegated)
- Sign in and read user profile (Delegated)

Microsoft Graph

- Read and write calendars in all mailboxes (Application) **(NEW)**
- Read and write all users' full profiles (Application)
- Read and write directory data (Application)
- Send mail as any user (Application) **(NEW)**

[image: Scopes Accept Page]

Thanks!

Comment: When you request the ID Token are you requesting a specific resource or leaving it blank? Did you have an Administrator go through the Admin Consent flow before testing with a normal user?

Comment: We don't specify a resource on `/common/oauth2/authorize` but we do send  `resource=https://graph.microsoft.com` (if not specified we get a 400 from the endpoint) on the `/common/oauth2/token` call. Yes we have users reauth using `prompt=admin_consent` on next login.

Comment: `prompt=admin_consent` forces the Admin Consent flow, `prompt=consent` is used for force User Consent. They are different things. Have you tried `prompt=consent`?

Comment: If I am requesting application scopes, in order to use them offline, I would want the admin to accept those scopes correct?

Comment: I attempted `prompt=consent` instead of `prompt=admin_consent`. No difference in the original problem. The new scopes are still not present in the response body nor the JWT token.

Comment: Have you also a tenant admin go through the `prompt=admin_consent` flow? Both are required.

Comment: Our app is only ever installed through the tenant admin and never requires a end user to accept. When we update scopes, we ask the admin to reconsent using the `admin_consent` prompt. The scopes we aren't getting are application level scopes.

Comment: That is pretty odd.. Multi-tenant apps can be a bit difficult because of this. I think in the past I had to delete the service principal from another tenant entirely and then run admin consent again. I was lucky to be in control of that tenant. Having `prompt=admin_consent` on the authorize call should be enough, and the necessary appRoleAssignments should be created.. (for the app permissions)

Comment: Out of interest, is there a reason that you are using Azure AD Graph, as well as Microsoft Graph? Why isn't calling Microsoft Graph sufficient?  For your issue, if consent is given in a new tenant (that has not consented yet) does everything work correctly?

Comment: And another question - you've added application permissions which would show up in the roles claim.  Have you checked there and are you calling using client_credential OAuth2 flow for your API requests to send mail and read/write calendars?

Comment: Appreciate the help Dan. I was able to consolidate all of our scopes under the Graph API. I'm currently requesting 4 'application' scopes and 1 'delegated' scope. The delegated scope is "Access As User" this is so we can add a new Directory Role.

So when I just request application scopes now, it works fine, all 4 come through. When I begin asking for the 1 delegated scope, then it is now the only scope that comes back during the token exchange. Any ideas why?
 Everything else is the same, `prompt=admin_consent`. A admin is still the one accepting scopes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make a token request against AAD v1 by specifying a specific resource, the access token returned will contain only the scopes required to access that specific resource. The details and example of the protocol is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code#use-the-authorization-code-to-request-an-access-token).

Therefore, if you need to access two resources you will need to request access token for each of them and the corresponding tokens will contain the scopes specific to that resource.

In this case, if the AAD Graph scopes are available in MS Graph, you can consolidate them under the MS Graph and request a single token for MS Graph. During the auth flow, you can control which of these scopes you want to request consent for by specifying them in the `scope` field of the auth request as mentioned in the description of the parameter [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-openid-connect-code#send-the-sign-in-request).